# Formatting a profile url with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm currently making a website and i need to rewrite the profile url with htaccess, i'm making internal profile pages, such as photos, albums etc.. And i need the url example.com/INSERT_USER_HERE/photos, where INSERT_USER_HERE points to the actual user and photos points to the "sub-page" to load, /photos will need to be captured in the profile.php so it needs to point to a GET variable.

Here is the current RewriteRule for the profile page:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another `rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(photos|albims)/?$ profile.php?user=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Now if URL is `/john/photos` it will internally call `/profile.php?user=john&page=photos` and you can work with `$_GET` array inside `/profile.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped so much